# Is it okay for me to implement a switch statement in the onCreate method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, switch-statement, oncreate

I currently have an activity's onCreate() method set to capture an intent the first thing it does. The intent will always have an extra int "ACTIONCODE" that determines what the activity should do.

Activity A might want activity Z to set up variables for the first time, so it calls startActivity(includedIntent) which has some extra int ActivityZ.SET_UP_FIRST_TIME (which is a constant in Activity Z.) Activity B might want to change the variables around a bit, so it does a startActivity(includedIntent) with the intent now including an extra int ActivityZ.CHANGE_VARIABLES as well as other data to change those variables.

Activity Z could just be a bunch of textviews that display what its variables are. Depending on what ACTIONCODE it receives from getIntent(), it will perform things just as it needs to.

**I feel like I have a lot more control over the activities in my app my doing this, yet I fear as though it might be a really naive and inefficient implementation**. I basically do not trust (nor fully understand) onStart(),onResume(),onPause(),and onStop(). From what I've heard, there is no guarantee that an activity will always return back to onResume(). While it was in its onPause() or onStop() state, it could have been killed or completely destroyed by the system, and thus would only return back to onCreate() again. It's the only method that I trust.

I even do all of my data saving from onCreate(). Why? I heard that if an activity is in onPause() or onStop(), it is liable to be killed, and may not even finish running through all the lines included in the overridden onPause() or onStop() method. I don't want to perform a data saving function from within a method that could abruptly stop!

Is my thinking wrong here? Are my fears irrational? If so, what should I do instead?

Here are my app screenshots by the way:
    [image: 1]
    [image: 2]
    [image: 3]
    [image: 4]

Comment: You should read the activity lifecycle . `onResume()` will always be called(in either of the scenarios you mention) as it's the callback that will get called right before an activity will be visible(so it doesn't matter if it was previously destroyed or not). `onPause` it's guaranteed to run, after this the activity could be killed(an starting from Honeycomb the same applies to `onPause()`). Maybe I don't understand your scenario but why bother calling an activity if you plan to call immediately other activities from within that activity?

Comment: @Luksprog: Well, thus far I have a ProfileLoadMenu activity, an ActiveMenu activity, and ProfileOptions activity. The first just lets the user load a profile from an ArrayList. ActiveMenu displays the currently loaded profile with all of its variables and whatnot. ProfileOptions is straightforward. Perhaps I'm just abusing activities and not really using the right things to set up my app with. Should I use 3 separate intents for those 3 things, or do something else?

Comment: If in the `ProfileLoadeMenu` you just select a profile then it doesn't really make sense to be an activity on its own. If you still want to have distinct windows then I would use two fragments in `ActiveMenu` and pass to this activity an indicator on which of the two fragments to show(this depends on what it should happen when the user currently selects a profile in ProfileLoadMenu). As, for the ProfileOptions, that could be an activity on its own, I don't understand however why it should be started directly from onCreate. An image with the screens of your app would be very helpful.

Comment: @Luksprog I have added the screencaps.

Comment: @Luksprog Also, from what you're telling me, the first time an app runs, it will run the onCreate() for an activity, yes? After that, it goes down either the onPause/onResume or onStop/onRestart route, or even gets destroyed. I should be implementing saving at onPause, and redrawing at onStart()? Variable initialization happened during onCreate, and it won't be lost in memory if the activity gets destroyed, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Luksprog. After some reading, I think I can trust the activity lifecycle better now.
I will implement setting up in onCreate, loading in onResume, and saving in onPause! Hopefully that's correct.

Now all I need is some advice on the right way to set up activities and fragments. I just need some general rule of thumb for deciding when and when not to start a new activity, or if it may be better to use fragments.

Comment: Deciding between activities only or activities with fragments isn't quite straightforward. Fragments were introduced to handle the multiple screen sizes between the various android devices so if you want to make a phone/tablet optimized app then use fragments.

Comment: @Luksprog Well, I suppose I could always convert my activities to fragments later, if I decide to optimize for tablets. I'll just stick to learning with activities only for now.